# Why we need SharedResources class while doing localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net core localization, and trying to use resource files. There are multiple ways of doing it, so I started with IStringLocalizer and IHtmlLocalizer.

We can specify the type while injecting the Localizer into the view, and most of the tutorial recommend to create an Empty **SharedResource** class file with root namespace.

I tried to find the reason behind it but didn't find, Could anyone please help me out about the reason of having the empty **SharedResource** class?

```cs
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResources> Localizer


namespace Root.Namespace
{
    public class SharedResources
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

empty SharedResource class is use to group your resource file in Visual studio like this

[image]

[image]

Also it need for IStringLocalizeFactory

```
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
            {
                options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                {
                    var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                    return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
                };
            });
```

You can read my blog and source code [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/05/25/localization-for-asp-net-core-2-2/) to understand it better